# Customizer - Prefix Class Extension

Tags: php, theme-customizer, theme-options, oop

I have a basic question to beautiful working code I've found (paulund) for making a Custom Control by extending the 'WP_Customize_Control' Class. I am new to PHP, Programming and especially to OOP. So I wonder especially, what the first "condition" do, while the rest seems comprehensibly to me. I have a understanding problem with:

```
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Customize_Control' ) )
    return NULL;
```

Read the php manual for "class_exists" and I read in a german blog, that the code above ensures, that we have no conflicts with other Plugins... .

I this is the idea of it, how does it work? 
Shouldn't the Class exist by Wordpress Core anyway? Sorry for my English. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible way to make sure you are in the right context. The normal way is to load your class only when it is really needed, not earlier.

A side effect is that the following code cannot be cached, because that line is evaluated on *run time*, not on *compile time*. The same applies to `function_exists()`.

Summary: Don't do that.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I have to dive deeper into OOP to find a better way to avoid conflicts. Might spl_autoload_register () will provide a better solution? But to be honest... . I will need a few weeks to built up the basic know-how in OOP. Meanwhile and once again many thanks.

Comment: @FriedrichSiever Yes, do use autoloading. Preferably [Coposer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) or a [simple alternative](https://gist.github.com/toscho/ee39d04966e911e66256970f7ce4c1b8).